# My output format is not correct can someone help me?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, data-structures

Given an unsorted list of integers, output the integers in order.

Sample Input

`100 63 25 73 1 98 73 56 84 86 57 16 83 8 25 81 56 9 53 98 67 99 12 83 89 80 91 39 86 76 85 74 39 25 90 59 10 94 32 44 3 89 30 27 79 46 96 27 32 18 21 92 69 81 40 40 34 68 78 24 87 42 69 23 41 78 22 6 90 99 89 50 30 20 1 43 3 70 95 33 46 44 9 69 48 33 60 65 16 82 67 61 32 21 79 75 75 13 87 70 33`

Sample Output

`1 1 3 3 6 8 9 9 10 12 13 16 16 18 20 21 21 22 23 24 25 25 25 27 27 30 30 32 32 32 33 33 33 34 39 39 40 40 41 42 43 44 44 46 46 48 50 53 56 56 57 59 60 61 63 65 67 67 68 69 69 69 70 70 73 73 74 75 75 76 78 78 79 79 80 81 81 82 83 83 84 85 86 86 87 87 89 89 89 90 90 91 92 94 95 96 98 98 99 99`

My Output

`11  33   6  8 99 10  12 13   1616  18  20 2121 22 23 24 252525  2727   3030  323232 333333 34     3939 4040 41 42 43 4444  4646  48  50   53   5656 57  59 60 61  63  65  6767 68 696969 7070   7373 74 7575 76  7878 7979 80 8181 82 8383 84 85 8686 8787  898989 9090 91 92  94 95 96  9898 9999`

my code:

```
a=int(input())
b=input()
b1=b.split(" ")
arr=list(map(int,b1))
ans=[]
for i in range(0,100,1):
    #print(arr.count(i),end=' ')
    ans.append(arr.count(i))
for i in range(0,len(ans)):
    if(i==0):
        continue
    else:
        print(str(i)*ans[i],end=' ')
```

Comment: why not use `sort()` ?

Comment: @Idos I'd imagine this is a homework question

Comment: nope it was challenge question but i lost the challenge, so i wanted to know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you *have to* do it that way, try:

```
print((str(i) + ' ') * ans[i], end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *sorted* with key:

```
string = "100 63 25 73 1 98 73 56 84 ... "

sorted_string = " ".join(sorted(string.split(), key=lambda x: int(x)))
```

Comment: i'm new to regular expressions, can you tell me a place where i can read about lambda expressions in python?